# How do I add shaded regions to a line chart with multiple lines using ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, linechart

I have a dataset on two county's population over time:

```
 dat <- data.frame(Year=rep(c(2012, 2013, 2014, 2015), each=2),
                     Region=rep(c("County1", "County2"), 4),
                     Count=c(125082, 122335, 126474, 121661, 128220, 121627, 130269, 121802))
```

I'm able to do a line chart just fine:

```
ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=Year, y=Count, group=Region, fill = Region)) +
geom_line()
```

[image]

However, I want to be super cool and fill in the regions below the lines with color. When I try to use geom_area(), it seems to stack county2 over county1:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=Year, y=Count, fill = Region)) + geom_area()
```

[image]

That's not what I want. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Check out `geom_ribbon`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reshape your data to wide format and then use `geom_ribbon()` to fill the area between `County1` and `County2` lines:

```
library(ggplot2); library(reshape2)
ggplot(dcast(Year ~ Region, data = dat), aes(x = Year)) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = County1, ymax = County2, fill = "band")) + 
  scale_fill_manual("", values = "#AA44CC") + ylab('count')
```

[image]

To fill multiple ribbons, simply add another layer of ribbon, to visualize the result better, we start from `121000` here:

```
ggplot(dcast(Year ~ Region, data = dat), aes(x = Year)) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = County1, ymax = County2, fill = "red"))  + ylab('Count') + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = 121000, ymax = County2, fill = "green"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how I could add a second ribbon for county2 (i.e., to go from the bottom of the plot to county2's values)?

Comment: You can add another layer of ribbon with `ymin` to be the bottom line and `ymax` to be `county2` values, see the update.